# Render and test UI components Individually in angular 6

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, angular6

I'm building **Angular 6** project and I need to test the appearance of **angular component** without assigning router link and manually loading it. I need to view individual component and how it behave.  I don't have much understanding in unit tests in angular. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `spec` file associated with each `component` file (usually generated if you generate component using command `ng g component new`). This spec file supports unit testing. You need not load entire app to perform unit testing certain component.

If you go through the official [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-class-testing), you will understand how unit testing works.

**Note** : When you run entire unit test cases, each `spec` file will execute independently, which means each file has its own configuration required to support unit testing of associated `component`

Comment: But how to test appearance of a component?

Comment: Did you go through the documentation from the link I have provided? It has all the details to test your component template and it's behavior. You question is too broad.. If you had tried something then I could help with the issue. To start with testing, please go through the documentation